# Object is not iterable - Django

Tags: django

I'm having an object "Movie" not iterable, I can't find my errors. I have two similar views I'm wondering if it's the issue. I want to display just 5 actors and then a link to see all actors from the movie.

Could you please give me a hand?
Thanks

template:

View.py

```
def home(request):
    date = datetime.date.today()
    start_week = date - datetime.timedelta(date.weekday())
    end_week = start_week + datetime.timedelta(7)
    movie_semaine = Movie.objects.filter(release_date__range=[start_week, end_week])[:4]
    #descending order by '-release_date'
    movie_cinema = Movie.objects.filter(is_available_in_theaters=True).order_by('-release_date')[:4]
    context = {'movies_list': movie_semaine, 'movies_cinema': movie_cinema}
    return render(request, 'bms/visitor/index.html', context)

def movies(request):
    all = Movie.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'films.html', {'films': all})

def movie_detail(request, id):
    #movie = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=id)
    #order by order column to get only the Top 5 Actors
    role = Role.objects.filter(movie=movie).order_by("order")[:5]
    actor = Actor.objects.filter(movie_list=movie)
    #cinema = Cinema.objects.filter(movies=movie)
    return render(request, 'bms/visitor/film.html', {'movies': movie, 'roles': role, 'actors': actor})

def movie_actors(request, id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=id)
    role = Role.objects.filter(movie=movie)
    actor = Actor.objects.filter(movie_list=movie)
    return render(request, 'bms/visitor/actors.html', {'movies': movie, 'roles': role, 'actors': actor})

def movie_review(request, id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'bms/visitor/critique.html', {'movies': movie})

def actor_detail(request, id):
    #movie = Movie.objects.get(pk=id)
    actor = Actor.objects.get(pk=id)
    role = Role.objects.filter(actor=actor)
    return render(request, 'bms/visitor/actor.html', {'roles': role, 'actors': actor})
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: @What line has the error?

Comment: Sure : http://dpaste.com/1WGPG9S

Comment: You pass `'movies': movie`, but `movie` is a *single* `Movie` object, not a collection of movies, hence `{% for movie in movies %}` makes no sense. The same with `'actors': actor`, etc.

Comment: The times when you are only retrieving a single movie I would suggest using [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) so that your app gracefully handles cases where a user tries to go to a movie that no longer exists or just enters a random `id`

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. Regarding my issue it's only when I want to display the movie_actors view that it's doesn't work, the rest is ok. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you please share your models.py for Movie, Role, Actor class

Comment: Can you share the template for the `movie_actors` view?

Comment: movie_actors template :http://dpaste.com/1N5F9JN   movie_detail template : http://dpaste.com/33FVTJ6

Comment: The issue in the `movie_actors` template is that you are trying to iterate over a single Movie instance `{% for actor in movies %}`. Can you share your models? There are for more elegant ways of looping over related objects than what you are currently attempting

Comment: I started django few weeks ago, still learning, http://dpaste.com/0NW15M4 thanks

Comment: For example in the `movie_detail` view, you only need to pass `movie` in the context. All other related objects can be accessed via relationships in the template. `{% for actor in movie.actors.all %}` and `{% for role in movie.role_set.all|slice:":5" %}`